# Calculating Time Difference

Tags: python, time

at the start and end of my program, I have

```
from time import strftime
print int(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")



Y1=int(strftime("%Y"))
m1=int(strftime("%m"))
d1=int(strftime("%d"))
H1=int(strftime("%H"))
M1=int(strftime("%M"))
S1=int(strftime("%S"))


Y2=int(strftime("%Y"))
m2=int(strftime("%m"))
d2=int(strftime("%d"))
H2=int(strftime("%H"))
M2=int(strftime("%M"))
S2=int(strftime("%S"))

print "Difference is:"+str(Y2-Y1)+":"+str(m2-m1)+":"+str(d2-d1)\
          +" "+str(H2-H1)+":"+str(M2-M1)+":"+str(S2-S1)
```

But when I tried to get the difference, I get syntax errors.... I am doing a few things wrong, but I'm not sure what is going on...

Basically, I just want to store a time in a variable at the start of my program, then store a 2nd time in a second variable near the end, then at the last bit of the program, compute the difference and display it. I am not trying to time a function speed. I am trying to log how long it took for a user to progress through some menus. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Think about what happens if the user starts at 8:59:34 and finishes at 9:10:12

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime) module will do all the work for you:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> # ...wait a while...
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(b-a)
0:03:43.984000
```

If you don't want to display the microseconds, just use (as gnibbler suggested):

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
>>> print(b-a)
0:03:43
```

Comment: @gnibbler: Hey, nice. Much better than messing with string indices.

Comment: you can use c=b-a ,str(c) to get '0:03:43' string

Comment: One flaw: Doesn't use monotonic time. I suppose the difference will be wrong when transitioning to/from daylight saving time, and whenever ntpd adjusts your clock.

Answer (score 29):

```
from time import time

start_time = time()
...

end_time = time()
seconds_elapsed = end_time - start_time

hours, rest = divmod(seconds_elapsed, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(rest, 60)
```

Answer (score 13):

You cannot calculate the differences separately ... what difference would that yield for 7:59 and 8:00 o'clock? Try

```
import time
time.time()
```

which gives you the seconds since the start of the epoch.

You can then get the intermediate time with something like

```
timestamp1 = time.time()
# Your code here
timestamp2 = time.time()
print "This took %.2f seconds" % (timestamp2 - timestamp1)
```

Answer (score 12):

Both [time.monotonic()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) and [time.monotonic_ns()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic_ns) are correct. Correct as in monotonic.

```
>>> import time
>>>
>>> time.monotonic()
452782.067158593
>>>
>>> t0 = time.monotonic()
>>> time.sleep(1)
>>> t1 = time.monotonic()
>>> print(t1 - t0)
1.001658110995777
```

Regardless of language, *monotonic time* is the right answer, and *real time* is the wrong answer, for consistently measuring durations that aren't very long. Monotonic time exists to give a consistent answer when measuring durations, while real time may be adjusted – indeed *needs* to be adjusted – to keep up with reality. Monotonic time is usually the computer's uptime.

As such, [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) and [datetime.now()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime) are wrong ways to do this.

Python also has [time.perf_counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) and [time.perf_counter_ns()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns), which are specified to have the highest available resolution, but aren't guarranteed to be monotonic. On PC hardware, though, both typically have nanosecond resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a piece of code to do so:

def(StringChallenge(str1)):

```
#str1 = str1[1:-1]
h1 = 0
h2 = 0
m1 = 0
m2 = 0

def time_dif(h1,m1,h2,m2):
    if(h1 == h2):
        return m2-m1
    else:
        return ((h2-h1-1)*60 + (60-m1) + m2)
count_min = 0

if str1[1] == ':':
    h1=int(str1[:1])
    m1=int(str1[2:4])
else:
    h1=int(str1[:2])
    m1=int(str1[3:5])

if str1[-7] == '-':
    h2=int(str1[-6])
    m2=int(str1[-4:-2])
else:
    h2=int(str1[-7:-5])
    m2=int(str1[-4:-2])

if h1 == 12:
    h1 = 0
if h2 == 12:
    h2 = 0

if "am" in str1[:8]:
    flag1 = 0
else:
    flag1= 1

if "am" in str1[7:]:
    flag2 = 0
else:
    flag2 = 1

if flag1 == flag2:
    if h2 > h1 or (h2 == h1 and m2 >= m1):
        count_min += time_dif(h1,m1,h2,m2)
    else:
        count_min += 1440 - time_dif(h2,m2,h1,m1)
else:
    count_min += (12-h1-1)*60
    count_min += (60 - m1)
    count_min += (h2*60)+m2


return count_min
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.