# Subtract Two DateTime objects - Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have two date time objects like this

```
a = first date time object
b = second date time object
```

And then

```
c = a - b
```

Now I want to compare c and check if the difference was greater than 3 hours, so I have a time object called `three_hours`

```
three_hours = datetime.time(3,0)
if c >= three_hours:
     #do stuff
```

but I get an error saying cannot compare datetime.teimdelta to datetime.time

My question is different as I also want to then compare the subtracted time, not just get the difference!!

How can I convert them to the correct formats so I can check if 3 hours has passed?

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426870/calculating-time-difference

Comment: The value of datetime.timedelta object d can be converted to hours with d.days*24 + (d.seconds + d.microseconds*10**6)/3600

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When you subtract two datetime objects in python, you get a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object. You can then get the `total_seconds()` for that timedelta object and check if that is greater than `3*3600` , which is the number of seconds for 3 hours. Example -

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime.datetime(2015,8,25,0,0,0,0)
>>> c = a - b
>>> c.total_seconds()
87062.729491
>>> c.total_seconds() > 3*3600
True
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also just compare to another timedelta object

```
import datetime
if c >= datetime.timedelta(hours=3):
   #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
three_hours = 3600*3 # in seconds

if c.total_seconds() >= three_hours:
    # do stuff
```