# Django time field difference

Tags: python, django

I need to compare two time fields value and calculate total worked hours.

My function (What I tried)

```
def difft(start,end):
    a,b,c,d = start.hour, start.minute, start.second, start.microsecond
    w,x,y,z = end.hour, end.minute, end.second, end.microsecond
    delt = (w-a)*60 + (x-b) + (y-c)/60. + (z-d)/60000000
    return delt + 1440 if delt<0 else delt

def myfunction():
    attendance = StaffAttendance.objects.get(id=1)

    time_sheets = []    

    t_times = TimeSheet.objects.filter(staff_attendance=attendance,is_deleted=False).order_by("time")
    for t in t_times:
        time_sheets.append(t.time)

    #timesheets = [datetime.time(4, 0), datetime.time(6, 0)]

    total_time = 0
    times = []

    for time in time_sheets: 
        if time in times:
            m = difft(times[0],time)
            total_time += m
            times = []
        else:
            times.append(time)
```

`if time in times:` this block always return `False`.

How can I  calculate total hours worked from django time fields. I'm new to Python/Django. So I don't know too much about python date. Could you please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you put a print statement to see what the values of `time_sheets` and `times` are in the loop ?

Comment: `if time in times:` will always return false because `times` is an empty list (`[]`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Time Difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426870/calculating-time-difference)

Answer (score 0):

If time_sheets has unique time datas, your if statement will always return false. I am confused about what you want to do in for loop. Maybe you want to check if time not in times, as a result you get times not processed and you can use difft function and you can append processed time into times list.