# How to use the timedate with an input statement

Tags: python

I'm having a lot of trouble doing this. Only just started using python.

Define a function called compute_opening_duration to calculate the duration of the opening time. 
The function takes two strings: the opening time and the closing time as the inputs and return the opening duration in hours.
The opening time and the closing time are in the form 'Hour:Minute:Second'.
If the opening time or the closing time are not in the correct form, the function returns -1.

Example: 
opening time: '8:30:00', closing time: '16:00:00', return 7.5
opening time: '9:00:00', closing time: '16:15:00', return 7.25
opening time: '8:30:00', closing time: 'evening', return -1

Hint: you might want to use datetime package

**MY CODE**

```
import datetime

x= input('opening time: ')
y= input('closing time: ')

t = datetime.time(8:30:0)

z= datetime.time(16:0:0)

def compute_opening_duration(t, z):

     if true
       return 7.5

    elif
     if false
       return 7.25

    else
      return -1
```

File "", line 18
    t = datetime.time(8:30:0)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: To be clear, you would like to calculate the difference between two times, `t` and `z` in this case, is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Time Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426870/calculating-time-difference)