# How to automatically calculate time between two different dates with two tags in Python?

Tags: python, csv, date, difference

I started a small project with my friends where we track our Discord voice chat activity. The extracted data looks like this:

| user | action | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userA#1234 | join | 2021-09-07 15:05:35 |
| userB#5678 | join | 2021-09-07 15:06:21 |
| userA#1234 | leave | 2021-09-07 17:04:40 |
| userB#5678 | leave | 2021-09-07 17:04:41 |

This data is stored as a csv-file. I now want to modify it to get a new csv showing the duration like this:

| user | join_time | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userA#1234 | 2021-09-07 15:05:35 | 01:59:05 |
| userB#5678 | 2021-09-07 15:06:21 | 01:58:20 |

Is there a good way to automate this process?

Comment: I would suggest using pandas for working with tables. And for extracting the time from the date-time string just use datetime.split(" ")[1]. Or you could use this thread for finding an answer to calculating the time difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426870/calculating-time-difference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would pivot and find the difference

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df_p = df.pivot('user', 'action', 'datetime')
df_p['duration'] = df_p.diff(axis=1)['leave']
df_p.to_csv('path/to/new/file.csv')

action                    join               leave        duration
user                                                              
userA#1234 2021-09-07 15:05:35 2021-09-07 17:04:40 0 days 01:59:05
userB#5678 2021-09-07 15:06:21 2021-09-07 17:04:41 0 days 01:58:20
```

Comment: I think the fact that users join and leave multiple times leads to an error. In my example, imagine that userA re-joins an hour later.